# Does the derived category remember the homological dimension?

Tags: homological-algebra

Question:

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category and $D^?(\mathcal{A})$ be its derived category, where ? could be empty, +, - or b (for boundedness). Is it possible to recover the homological dimension of $\mathcal{A}$ from the derived category?

Here I'm using the term homological dimension in the sense of Gelfand-Manin, i.e. if for all $X,Y\in\mathcal{A}$, $\text{Ext}\_{\mathcal{A}}^i(X,Y):=\text{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(X[0],Y[i])=0$, then the homological dimension is said to be less than $i$. The homological dimension is the maximal $n$ such that there exists a non-vanishing $\text{Ext}^n(X,Y)$.

Note that in the derived category one could have all kinds of non-vanishing $\text{Ext}^n(X,Y)$, as $X,Y $ can be complexes shifted arbitrarily. Is it still possible to recover this information via other method?

Comment: Assuming $\mathcal{A}$ is the entire category of modules over a ring $R$, if $R$ is local or commutative then $D^{b}(Mod R)$ determines $R$ up to Morita equivalence.

Comment: No, you also need the t-structure on the derived category.

Comment: If the derived category is the bounded derived category of a smooth projective variety, then you can recover its dimension from point like object, because every point like object have a codimension, and they are all equal to dim$X$. see Huybrechts' book on Fourier-Mukai.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, $\mathcal{A}$ be the abelian category of finitely generated graded modules over the symmetric algebra $S(V)$, and $\mathcal{B}$ be the abelian category of finitely generated graded modules over the exterior algebra $\Lambda(V^*)$.  Then the bounded derived categories $\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{A})$ and $\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{B})$ are naturally equivalent.  This is called the Bernstein-Gelfand-Gelfand duality, a particular case of Koszul duality.  On the other hand, the homological dimension of $\mathcal{A}$ is equal to $\dim V$, while the homological dimension of $\mathcal{B}$ is infinite.

To obtain a similar example with unbounded derived categories, let $\mathcal{A}^+$ be the abelian category of (infinitely generated) nonnegatively graded $S(V)$-modules and $\mathcal{B}^+$ be the abelian category of nonnegatively graded $\Lambda(V^\ast)$-modules.  Here it is presumed that $S(V)$ is graded so that $V$ is placed in the degree $1$, while $\Lambda(V^\ast)$ is graded so that $V^*$ is placed in the degree $-1$.  Then the unbounded derived categories $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A}^+)$ and $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{B}^+)$ are equivalent.

UPDATE.  I was asked in the comments to provide an example with both homological dimensions being finite.  This can be done by yet another modification of the above examples.  Pick an integer $n>\dim V$.  Let $\mathcal{A}_n$ be the abelian category of finitely generated graded $S(V)$-modules concentrated in the gradings $0\leq i\leq n$.  Similarly, let $\mathcal{B}_n$ be the abelian category of finitely generated graded $\Lambda(V^\ast)$-modules concentrated in the gradings $0\leq i\leq n$.  Then the homological dimension of $\mathcal{A}_n$ is equal to $\dim V$, the homological dimension of $\mathcal{B}_n$ is equal to $n$, and $\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{A}_n)\simeq\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{B}_n)$.  A similar example with unbounded derived categories can be obtained by removing the finitely generatedness assumption.

All of the above counterexamples presume that $\dim V>0$.  The only positive result in the direction of the original question that I can think of at the moment is that if the derived categories of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are equivalent, and $\mathcal{A}$ has homological dimension $0$, then so does $\mathcal{B}$.  Indeed, $\mathcal{A}$ is a semisimple abelian category if and only if $\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{A})$ and $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$ are.

Comment: Do there exist examples when both of the dimensions are finite?

Comment: Yes, they do.  See update.

Answer (score 13):

There are lots of examples to be found in the theory of tilted algebras.

A tilted algebra $B$ is an algebra of the form $\operatorname{End}_A(T)$ with $A$ an hereditary finite dimensional algebra (over an algebraically closed field, say) and $T$ a [tilting $A$-module](http://eom.springer.de/T/t130120.htm). Then $B$ and $A$ have equivalent derived categories, but $B$ is usually not hereditary (that is, its global dimension is usually bigger than $1$; one does have $\operatorname{gldim}B\leq2$, though, so it does not blow up too much).

A concrete example: let $A$ be the path algebra of the quiver $$\bullet \leftleftarrows \bullet \leftarrow \bullet$$ Number the vertices $1$, $2$ and $3$ from left to right, and let $T$ be the direct sum of the simple $S(1)$ and the indecomposable injective modules $I(1)$ and $I(3)$, which is a tilting module. Then $B=\operatorname{End}_A(T)$ is the algebra given by the same quiver, but bound by the relations given by the two paths of length two. In particular, $B$ is *not* hereditary.

You will find all this discussed at length in Assem, Simson and Slowroński's book *Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras*, Vol. 1.

If one considers more generally tilting *complexes* as opposed to just *modules*, then the difference between the global dimensions of the algebras involved can be made as large as you want.

Comment: The link to `eom.springer.de` is broken, but the article can now be found at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Tilting_module.